# E: Unable to locate package barrier

Tags: raspbian-stretch, software-installation, apt, packages, repository

I am trying to install [barrier](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/share-your-keyboard-and-mouse-between-computers-with-barrier/) on my raspberry pi so to enable sharing my mouse and keyboard over LAN.

However when I run the command:

```
$ sudo apt install barrier -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
```

I checked the apt-cache to see if I could it barrier

```
$ apt-cache search barrier
at-spi - Assistive Technology Service Provider Interface
between - game about consciousness and isolation
execnet-doc - rapid multi-Python deployment (docs)
htcheck-php - Simple php interface to database generated by ht://Check
komi - Single player arcade game with Komi the Space Frog!
libatomic-ops-dev - A library for atomic operations (development files)
libconcurrent-java - utility classes for concurrent java programming
libcurator-recipes-java - Apache Curator Recipes
libpwiz-dev - library to perform proteomics data analyses (devel files)
libpwiz-doc - set of programs to perform proteomics data analyses (doc)
libpwiz-tools - ProteoWizard command line tools
libpwiz3 - library to perform proteomics data analyses (runtime)
libzthread-2.3-2 - Object-oriented synchronization library for C++
libzthread-dev - Object-oriented synchronization library for C++
msn-pecan - alternative MSN protocol plug-in for libpurple
msn-pecan-dbg - debugging symbols for msn-pecan
neverputt - 3D miniature golf game
neverputt-data - data files for Neverputt
php-hamcrest - This is the PHP port of Hamcrest Matchers
python-execnet - rapid multi-Python deployment (Python 2)
python3-execnet - rapid multi-Python deployment (Python 3)
scap-workbench - Scanning and tailoring tool for SCAP content
singularity-container - container platform focused on supporting "Mobility of Compute"
```

I even made sure my sources repo was fine

```
$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
#deb http://plug-mirror.rcac.purdue.edu/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ stretch main contrib non-free rpi


$ cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
deb http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
# Uncomment line below then 'apt-get update' to enable 'apt-get source'
#deb-src http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian/ stretch main ui
```

Yes I did do an sudo apt update prior to the me attempting to install barrier

Does anyone have idea to fix this issue?

Comment: perhaps you need to be running **buster** rather than **stretch**

Answer (score 1):

Install *Raspberry Pi OS* which has barrier in its repository.

You could try downloading from the [barrier website](https://github.com/debauchee/barrier/releases).